# create many subsets at once

Tags: r, function, subset

I have a large dataset based on some medical records so I cannot post a sample due to privacy restrictions, but I am trying to subset the one data frame into many. The goal is for each unique facility to be its own data frame so I can identify efficiency rates for each facility. I have tried the following code where df is the name of the data frame, Name is the name I will give to the subset, Location is the value of interest from the variable "Facility" from the original dataframe:

```
ratefunct <- function(df, Name, Facility) {Name <- subset(df, Facility, == "Location")
Name <- within(Name, {rate <- <-cumsum(Complete)/ cumsum(Complete+Incomplete) })}
```

but don't seem to be getting any results in my environment

Comment: see the [`split`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) function. e.g. `split(iris, iris$Species)`

Comment: split.data.frame() worked perfectly though I am not seeing how to save each Facility to its own dataframe

Comment: Usually better not to split the dataset. Using dplyr `group_by` and then you can run any function on each group with `do`

Comment: Illustrative dummy data would nonetheless be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're trying to store the results of `split` as separate data frames.

You can do so like this, using `assign`

```
dfL <- split(iris, iris$Species)

for (i in 1:length(dfL)){
  assign(paste0("df_", names(dfL[i])), dfL[i])

# added the print line so you can see the names of the objects that are created

  print(paste0("df_",names(dfL[i])))

}

[1] "df_setosa"
[1] "df_versicolor"
[1] "df_virginica"
```

Which will create data frames `df_setosa`, `df_virginica`, and `df_versicolor`

---

Alternatively, if you're happy with the current object names, you could simply use:

```
list2env(dfL,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Which will save each list item as an object, using the object's name in the list. So instead of having the `df_` prefix, you would just have `setosa`, `virginica`, and `versicolor` objects.

---

**Edit:** as a simpler way to assign custom names to each created object, directly specifying the `names` of `dfL` is a nice clean solution:

```
names(dfL) <- paste0("df_",names(dfL))
list2env(dfL,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

This way you avoid having to write the `for` loop, and still get object names with a useful prefix.